# JSF2/Primefaces application gets .css.xhtml instead of .css

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I have an application in JSF2 and Primefaces. After include some .js and .css, when I open the website I have:
[image]

I don't know how to filter this to put it as static files and cache it.

I create a filter in web.xml like:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>staticFilesFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.test.application.filter.StaticFilesFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>staticFilesFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and when I am debugging it, it does not enter into the method doFilter. Always is entering in another filter that I have for .xhtml purposes (back button and other stuff..)

Any help to solve the filetype/format and also, how to get into the filter?

Comment: This is all normal (the extension), did you try to filter on `*.css.xhtml`? And before you start to develop all kinds of homegrown error prone things, look at what http://omnifaces.org/ can provide for you.

Comment: @Kukeltje yes, I have tried, but there is another filter with .xhtml and everything under .xhtml enter into this second filter

Comment: And what is the problem with that? Is it the jsf servlet? Or what?

Comment: The problem is the all css, js and png are not detecting as it is. The application returns all the static resources as a xhtml. The filter is not detecting it as a static. It detects as a .css.xhtml, so the filter applied is .xhtml instead of .css or .js

Comment: Read my comment about OmniFaces (and do something with it). I mention that for a reason: http://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/CDNResourceHandler